# Remove this specific audit in CV queue

Tags: support, specific-question, disputed-review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/21387650

This audit has a comment from OP that they posted a dupe of their own question. Seeing that that question in the comments had answers I opted to close as dupe of the linked post.

However it was an audit, considered a good post. Which is understandable seeing it has upvoted answers.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this audit needs to be removed, and I don't think this question should be closed.

OP replied to a comment asking *why are you looking to do this* with another question elaborating on a broader issue that can be answered with different approaches. That's not a duplicate, and as you can see, the answers to both questions are far from identical.

If anything, the second question is a bit broad because it asks for a *better approach* (since the first comment on his initial question hinted on the approach being illogical), but I think that one is on-topic as well.

Comment: The question I linked as the possible dupe states: "Although generally I've solved my case, I still want to know if there is an easier way to solve this problem?" So any answer to that question will have to be an answer to the question that I CV'd as a dupe.

Comment: No, that's just not true. Question 2 (your dupe target) asks about a broad problem, question 1 (the audit question) asks for a specific step in an attempt to solve that problem. The solution to question 2 can be (and is) a different approach than that attempt asked about in question 1, so it does not answer question 1, while it does solve the underlying issue. You could label question 1 as an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but that's not a valid reason to close it.